# C# FluentValidation for a hierarchy of classes

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a hierarchy of data classes

```
public class Base
{
    // Fields to be validated
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    // More fields to be validated
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    // More fields to be validated
}
```

What would be the appropriate way to validated Derived1 and Derived2 using FluentValidation framework without duplicating rules for fields of Base class?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

One approach to take would be as follows:

```
public class Base
{
    public string BaseName { get; set; } 
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public string Derived1Name { get; set; }
}

public class BaseValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : Base
{
    public BaseValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(b => b.BaseName).NotNull();
    }
}

public class Derived1Validator : BaseValidator<Derived1>
{
    public Derived1Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.Derived1Name).NotNull();
    }
}
```

So you first create your base validator, make it accept a generic type argument and specify that the generic type must be of type `base`. Set up your general rules for your base class and move on.

For any validators that validate children of your base class, you have those validators inherit from the baseValidator, where T will be your derived class type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! Noticed that there is no need to add : base() after the derived constructor. Initially, I had though it wont pick up the base tests without explicitly calling the base constructor. But it does!

Comment: You do not need to add base() if you have no constructors, because it is automatically there. If you had other constructors, apart from the default empty, then you must use base() using the signature you need. On the validation classes.. probably you will never need to add any other different constructors.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much! It's working perfectly.

Comment: What if I have a `ICollection<Base>` now and want to validate it?

Comment: I noticed with this approach the validation works on the server-side but the `data` attributes on the client-side don't get rendered with jquery unobtrusive validation so I had to use the `Include` method instead.

Answer (score 139):

```
public class Derived2Validator : AbstractValidator<Derived2>
{
    public Derived2Validator()
    {
        Include(new BaseValidator());
        Include(new Derived1Validator());
        RuleFor(d => d.Derived1Name).NotNull();
    }
}
```

`Derived2Validator` does not need to inherit `BaseValidator` or `Derived1Validator`.

Use the `Include` method to include the rules from other validators.

Comment: I'd go with this approach as it favours composition over inheritance which is a golden rule for good devs

Comment: `Include(new Derived2Validator());` isn't necessary, is it?

Comment: That would be an infinite loop if you included Include(new Derived2Validator());

Comment: I find the include really useful, but is there any way to easily test it?
The only way I have thought about is doing an interface for the validators in which I call an include method to return the instance.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the Include() method, but that did not give me desired results as models generated by swagger in .net core did not show any changes. what did work was creating a new class to inherit from for validators that have a base class

```
/// <summary>
/// Base Class for entity validator classes that specifies a base validator class
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The Type being validated</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TBaseClass">The validater assigned to the base type of the type being validated</typeparam>
public abstract class BaseAbstractValidator<T, TBaseClass> : AbstractValidator<T>
    where TBaseClass : IEnumerable<IValidationRule>
{
    protected BaseAbstractValidator() => AppendRules<TBaseClass>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the set of validation rules
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TValidationRule"></typeparam>
    private void AppendRules<TValidationRule>() where TValidationRule : IEnumerable<IValidationRule>
    {
        var rules = (IEnumerable<IValidationRule>)Activator.CreateInstance<TValidationRule>();
        foreach (var rule in rules)
        {
            AddRule(rule);
        }
    }
}
```