# Base Class Validations are not getting triggered with Fluent Validation in Asp.Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, razor-pages, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm using FluentValidation version: 8.5.1 in my Asp.Net Core 3.0 Razor Pages project.

I have a class derived from base class as shown below:

```cs
public class BranchEditViewModel : BranchViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to validate my derived class in my update method as shown below:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPutAsync([FromForm] BranchEditViewModel model)
```

But this doesn't work for some reason. The Validations are not getting called.

When I create `AbstractValidator` for my base class as shown below, the validator is not getting called.

```cs
public class BranchViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BranchViewModel>
```

But if I create `AbstractValidator` for my dervied class as shown below, the validator is getting called.

```cs
public class BranchViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BranchEditViewModel>
```

Please can you assist on why this is not working with base class? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The Base validator needs to be invoked manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36022690/10091607 and https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/738

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I made this working. I created a separate `BranchEditViewModelValidator` and then called `Include(new BranchViewModelValidator())` from it.

```cs
public class BranchEditViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BranchEditViewModel>
{
    public BranchEditViewModelValidator()
    {
        Include(new BranchViewModelValidator());
    }
}
```